# Python - Bibliotecas para MP3

Tags: python, pygame

Eu estou realizando um projeto baseado na linguagem Python e que requer bom desempenho na reprodução de Áudios (MP3). Atualmente eu estou usando o `PyGame` com o seu `pygame.mixer.music` para poder executar às músicas, porém esta  lib é muito fraca e reclusa, o que não permite avançar no desenvolvimento do software.

Gostaria de saber se há bibliotecas melhores para este caso, e que me permita de modo rápido e sem complicações, calcular o tempo de durabilidade e ter maior controle de volume nas aplicações, dentre outras.

Comment: Podes verificar esse componente : https://github.com/np1/mps. Parece ser completo.

Comment: @Bruno u acabei de baixar e instalar aqui, mas ele abre em linha de comando, creio que não é uma API, mas sim um software já feito (é o que aparenta)

Comment: [link](http://pymedia.org/) dá uma olhada no pymedia para python < 2.7, não existe caminhos fáceis quando o assunto é áudio hehe, a manipulação do áudio, para aumentar o diminuir volume pode ser feito depois do decode, o mesmo pode ser feito calculando o tamanho do vetor decodificado para saber o tamanho do áudio, qual versão de python está usando ?

Comment: @ederwander - Eu estou usando o Python 3.5, mas eu não entendo muito de manipulações de aúdio, agora eu estou criando uma coisa simples, mas enquanto eu tento algo simples eu tento algo avançado, usei o PyGame e tentei aprender o Mutagen, agora irei ver o PyMedia, em somando todos, qual você prefere?

Comment: @Félix PyMedia não tem suporte para python 3.5 :-(

Comment: @ederwander, isto é um problema

Answer (score 1):

Bom, eu ainda não entendi ao certo qual o seu objetivo com o projeto. Mas quando se trata de áudio, Python ainda é um pouco escasso. Porém, ainda assim existem algumas libs competentes para reprodução e/ou gravação de áudio como: [PySoundCard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySoundCard/0.5.2), [PyMedia](http://www.pymedia.org/), [playsound](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.1), [python-audio-tools](https://github.com/tuffy/python-audio-tools), [PyAudio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAudio/0.2.7) ou até o [PyGlet](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/media.html). Tente utilizar e aprender aquele que mais se adéqua a suas necessidades dentro dessa opções.